# Assigning the iterable new values

Tags: python

I want to find out if it's possible to assign new values to an iterable (say i).

My goal is to write a function that requests for some numbers and then perform a calculation with the numbers.

I can assign individual variable in the defined function but I want to find out if its possible to use a for loop instead.

example code:

```
def check_triangle():
    for i in range(3):
        i = int(input('Enter the number: \n'))
    is_triangle(i, i, i)
```

I want the value of I to have 3 different numbers but it seems to only keep the last number

Comment: One variable cannot hold more than one value, yes. You could make that one value a *list* into which you add multiple numbers in a loop, and then unpack those as arguments: `is_triangle(*i)`.

Comment: It might be less pedantic to ask for 3 numbers separated by a comma in one `input` call and then split them yourself.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this,

```
def check_triangle():
    is_triangle(*[int(input('Enter the number: \n')) for _ in range(3)])
```

You can store inputs in a list and pass it as argument to a function using `*`